# How to implement 301 permanent redirection using htaccess with custom parameter in URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, rules, permanent

Here I have a URL like [www.abc.com/product/women/casual/page:5/](http://www.abc.com/product/women/casual/page:5/) and I need to implement 301 permanent redirection using htaccess in order to change the URL to [www.abc.com/product/women/casual/page/5/](http://www.abc.com/product/women/casual/page/5/). In this case, parameter women and casual is customized category and subcategory and page:5 is page number 5. I need to change the last parameter page:5 to page/5 using htaccess 301 permanent redirection. Can anyone please help me to find a solution for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^:]+):5/$  /$1/5/
```

Or a more generic one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^:]+):([0-9])/?$ /$1/$2
```

This will redirect your old URL to the new one , for example `example.com/foo/bar:digit/` to `example.com/foo/bar/digit/` .

Or you can use `RewriteRule` directive

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^:]+):5/$ /$1/5/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not redirecting for me. Please suggest any other methods?

Comment: @TechTeam Sorry there was a typo. I updated the code and also added a RewriteRule.

Comment: Thankyou, Working for me